# Installing mojo and mojolicious problem

Tags: 22.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How to Install both mojo programming and mojolicious Perl on ubuntu wsl since both application name is same ie mojo how to run

Answer (score 1):

First, the applications are not named the same. One is "Mojolicious", which is a web development framework, the other is "Mojo", which is a programming language.

Mojolicious can be installed from the [Ubuntu Universe repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libmojolicious-perl) *(make sure to have the [Universe repo enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository))*.

```
sudo apt install libmojolicious-perl
```

The [Mojo PL](https://mojolang.org/) is not packaged for Ubuntu, and the SDK download requires a [developer login](https://developer.modular.com/signup). So best of luck with that.